# RhinoMocks - Unable to cast type foo to type bar when using non static Repository

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I am trying out RhinoMocks (only just started, please be gentle!) and am confused as to why if I use this setup:

```
var mockRepos = new MockRepository();
var mockServiceProvider = mockRepos.DynamicMock<IServiceProvider>(null);
var mockContext = mockRepos.DynamicMock<IPluginExecutionContext>(null);

mockServiceProvider.Expect(x => x.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext))).Return(mockContext);

var someSampleClass = new SomeClassOrOther(mockServiceProvider);
```

At some point in SomeClassOrOther, the method `GetService` is called

```
var context = (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext));
```

and causes the exception:

```
 Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.ObjectProxyd0bf4b879a6341bbba3478cf1189d621' to type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext'.
```

However if I use:

```
var mockServiceProvider = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IServiceProvider>(null);
var mockContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IPluginExecutionContext>(null);

mockServiceProvider.Expect(x => x.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext))).Return(mockContext);
```

i.e. the static `MockRepository.GenerateMock` and it executes with no errors.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Ah, I am using Expect. Should I be using Stub?

Comment: Use Stub if you don't verify the expectation later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you are getting this very exception. However, when using the "old" non-static syntax, you get mocks in "Record" state. Before using them, you need to set them in Replay mode:

```
var mockRepos = new MockRepository();
var mockServiceProvider = mockRepos.DynamicMock<IServiceProvider>();
var mockContext = mockRepos.DynamicMock<IPluginExecutionContext>();

mockRepos.ReplayAll();

mockServiceProvider
    .Stub(x => x.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext)))
    .Return(mockContext);

var someSampleClass = new SomeClassOrOther(mockServiceProvider);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing new `AAA` syntax and old `Record/Replay` syntax. When you are using `Expect` extension method and new `AAA` syntax, you don't need to operate on mocks repository and change its mode manually(Record/Replay). Create mocks with new static methods (which create mocks in replay mode) and verify expectations later:

```
// Arrange
var mockServiceProvider = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IServiceProvider>();
var mockContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IPluginExecutionContext>();

mockServiceProvider.Expect(x => x.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext)))
                   .Return(mockContext);

var someSampleClass = new SomeClassOrOther(mockServiceProvider);
// Act

// Assert
mockServiceProvider.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

Here is old `Record/Replay` syntax for comparison:

```
var mockRepos = new MockRepository();
var mockServiceProvider = mockRepos.DynamicMock<IServiceProvider>();
var mockContext = mockRepos.DynamicMock<IPluginExecutionContext>();

Expect.Call(mockServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext)))
      .Return(mockContext);
mockRepos.ReplayAll();

var someSampleClass = new SomeClassOrOther(mockServiceProvider);
// exercise your SUT
mockRepos.VerifyAll();
```